# Vector Space of Probability Density Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, random-variables, density-function

I'm wondering if it is possible to define a vector space $V$ of all valid probability density functions over $R^n$ (integrable functions in $R^n$ with area equal to 1).

Where the addition of two elements in this vector space, $f + g$, is defined to be their convolution $f*g$.

And multiplication by scalar $af$ is defined as $(af)(x)=\frac{f(x/a)}{a}$.

Does this form a vector space?

Comment: Independent to what? If one another (which your convolution identity seems to suggest), then this isn't true, since clearly $X+Y$ and $X$ are not independent, so both cannot be in the space.

Comment: There's a few issues - 1. your definition of scalar multiplication is off, since for dimension larger than one, $\int f(x/a) \,\mathrm{d} x = a^n \int f(x),$ not $a\int f(x)$. That's of course an easy fix. 2. The additive identity. You need a function $h$ s.t $f*h = f$ for every $f$. The obvious thing is of course the Dirac delta, but this is famously not a pdf, so you have to include the so called generalised pdfs. 3. The additive inverse might be tricky. It isn't obvious to me that for every $f$ there is a valid generalised pdf $g$ s.t.  $f * g = \delta$. (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) The intuitive reason why there shouldn't be one is the following - $f*g = \delta$ basically mean that for every random variable $X$ ($\sim f$), there exists an *independent* random variable $Y$ ($\sim g$) s.t. $X+Y$ is constant. This, at least on the face of it, seems absurd.

Comment: Thanks, you raised some good points. and I unfortunately have to agree with you on your third point. After doing a little searching though I did manage to find this https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/06/how_the_simplex_is_a_vector_sp.html which is casting all probability mass functions for a discrete random variable as a vector space. It might be possible to extend this to the pdf case

Comment: That's a really cool write-up, thanks! Yeah, it should be possible to extend this. Assuming some conditions like square integrability, you could naturally perform the process in the write-up with $L_2(\mathbb{R}^n).$ I'm not entirely sure how probabilistically meaningful this stuff is (e.g. - I don't quite understand how marginalisation of joint densities or the densities of independent vectors behave), but this is at the very least a super nice perspective on the max entropy shtick.